# Power BI Embedded for customers - Creating embeded URL

Tags: python, django, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm embedding a Power BI report on a "Embed for customer" manner and authenticating via service account. I have managed to get the embed token for a single report and a single workspace using Microsoft guides.

The issue comes when making a POST request to `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{workspace_id}/reports/{report_id}`. I get a 403 error.

Also, note that I am using Django and the final purpose is to process everything on the backend and just send a URL to the front end to put inside an iframe.

This is my Django View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Dashboard, ReportConfig, EmbedConfig, EmbedTokenRequestBody
from .serializer import DashboardSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from powerbi.aadservice import AadService

import requests
import json

class DashboardView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DashboardSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Retrieve the user's groups
        user = self.request.user
        user_groups = user.groups.all()

        # Filter the dashboards based on group membership
        queryset = Dashboard.objects.filter(group__in=user_groups)

        return queryset

class PbiEmbedService(View):
    def get(self, request, workspace_id, report_id, additional_dataset_id=None):
        '''Get embed params for a report and a workspace'''
        report_url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{workspace_id}/reports/{report_id}'
        api_response = requests.get(report_url, headers=self.get_request_header())

        if api_response.status_code != 200:
            return JsonResponse(
                {
                    'error': f'Error while retrieving Embed URL\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}'
                },
                status=api_response.status_code,
            )

        api_response = json.loads(api_response.text)
        report = ReportConfig(api_response['id'], api_response['name'], api_response['embedUrl'])
        dataset_ids = [api_response['datasetId']]

        # Append additional dataset to the list to achieve dynamic binding later
        if additional_dataset_id is not None:
            dataset_ids.append(additional_dataset_id)

        embed_token = self.get_embed_token_for_single_report_single_workspace(report_id, dataset_ids, workspace_id)
        embed_config = EmbedConfig(embed_token.tokenId, embed_token.token, embed_token.tokenExpiry, [report.__dict__])

        parsed_token = (embed_config.__dict__)
        access_token = parsed_token['token']

        #Here's where the issue starts
        embed_url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{workspace_id}/reports/{report_id}'
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}

        response = requests.post(embed_url, headers=headers)
        print(response)

        return JsonResponse(embed_config.__dict__)



    def get_request_header(self):
        '''Get Power BI API request header'''
        return {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AadService.get_access_token()}

    def get_embed_token_for_single_report_single_workspace(self, report_id, dataset_ids, target_workspace_id=None):
        '''Get Embed token for single report, multiple datasets, and an optional target workspace

        Args:
            report_id (str): Report Id
            dataset_ids (list): Dataset Ids
            target_workspace_id (str, optional): Workspace Id. Defaults to None.

        Returns:
            EmbedToken: Embed token
        '''

        request_body = EmbedTokenRequestBody()

        for dataset_id in dataset_ids:
            request_body.datasets.append({'id': dataset_id})

        request_body.reports.append({'id': report_id})

        if target_workspace_id is not None:
            request_body.targetWorkspaces.append({'id': target_workspace_id})

        # Generate Embed token for multiple workspaces, datasets, and reports. Refer https://aka.ms/MultiResourceEmbedToken
        embed_token_api = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken'
        api_response = requests.post(embed_token_api, data=json.dumps(request_body.__dict__), headers=self.get_request_header())

        if api_response.status_code != 200:
            return JsonResponse(
                {
                    'error': f'Error while retrieving Embed URL\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}'
                },
                status=api_response.status_code,
            )

        api_response = json.loads(api_response.text)
        embed_token = EmbedConfig(api_response['tokenId'], api_response['token'], api_response['expiration'], [])

        return embed_token
```

At the moment, what I got is:

```
{
    "tokenId": "REDACTED",
    "token": "REDACTED",
    "tokenExpiry": "2023-07-12T22:47:42Z",
    "reports": [
        {
            "id": "REDACTED",
            "name": "Supply Chain Sample",
            "embedUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=REDACTEDb&groupId=REDACTED&w=2&config=REDACTED"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Getting Embed URL, you need to send the **GET** request and not the **POST** request.

Refer [Get Report In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-report-in-group) Documentation for more details.

Comment: I'm already making a request to that endpoint, but the Embed URL doesn't seem to be loading anything. An example from Microsoft calls the embed method from a JS library to get the URL that goes into the iframe. That's the main issue I have

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/powerbi-client/2.15.1/powerbi.min.js

Comment: @RicardoTejada, If I understand correctly your scenario, We need to pass the embedConfig from the backend. We can embed only in frontend using the `powerbi.embed(reportContainer, loadConfig)` and it will embed the report.

Comment: LMK if you have any questions. It'll be great if you share how you are embedding in Front end to understand better.

Comment: That's it, I was trying to embed from the backend but it has to be done in front just as you said.

Comment: Glad, It resolved

Comment: Hey, I'd like to know if I can filter out the information that goes onto the report so that the user doesn't see stuff they shouldn't. AFAIK they can edit the URL when it gets exposed to the frontend, so is there a way to actually prevent them from seeing stuff they shouldn't?

Comment: Besides Query string parameters in URL, You can try Row Level Security. It restricts data access for specific users.  Refer this documentation on [Embedding Report with RLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/cloud-rls).

Comment: Embed report with RLS is only applies to **App Owns Data**.